# Algorithm to smooth numbers with variable input time

Tags: algorithm

I have an app that accepts integers at a variable rate every .25 to 2 seconds.

I'd like to output the data in a smoothed format for 3, 5 or 7 seconds depending on user input.

If the data always came in at the same rate, let's say every .25 seconds, then this would be easy.  The variable rate is what confuses me.

Data might come in like this:
**Time - Data**
0.25 - 100
0.50 - 102
1.00 - 110
1.25 - 108
2.25 - 107
2.50 - 102
ect...

I'd like to display a 3 second rolling average every .25 seconds on my display.

The simplest form of doing this is to put each item into an array with a time stamp.

```
array.push([0.25, 100])  
array.push([0.50, 102])  
array.push([1.00, 110])  
array.push([1.25, 108])
```

ect...

Then every .25 seconds I would read through the array, back to front, until I got to a time that was less than `now() - rollingAverageTime`.  I would sum that and display it.  I would then `.Shift()` the beginning of the array.

That seems not very efficient though.  I was wondering if someone had a better way to do this.

Comment: Are you applying any weighting based on the interval between each value and its predecessor/successor?

Comment: No, no weighting needed.

Comment: Ok, I thought I should just check.  Without the weighting, I'm not sure what a rolling average means here.  For instance, if I had [0.00,100], [0.25,1000], [1.75,100], then the rolling average calculated at t=2.00 would be 400, which takes no account of the fact that the majority of the time was spent at 1000.

Comment: yah, so I'm connecting to an extra device that sends data via a radio wave.  Devices try to stay at a constant rate, like .25.  Some setup at a constant rate of .5.  Sometimes I'll get drop outs due to interference.

The rolling average doesn't have to be super accurate.  It's more to calm the data on the display.  I still record the data point by point for later analysis.  

But you're right about it not meaning too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you save the timestamp of the starting value and then accumulate the values and the number of samples until you get a timestamp that is `>= startingTime + rollingAverageTime` and then divide the accumulator by the number of samples taken?

EDIT:
If you want to preserve the number of samples, you can do this way:

Take the accumulator, and for each input value sum it and store the value and the timestamp in a shift register; at every cycle, you have to compare the latest sample's timestamp with the oldest timestamp in the shift register plus the smoothing time; if it's equal or more, subtract the oldest saved value from the accumulator, delete that entry from the shift register and output the accumulator, divided by the smoothing time. If you iterate you obtain a rolling average with (i think) the least amount of computation for each cycle:

- a sum (to increment the accumulator)
- a sum and a subtraction (to compare the timestamp)
- a subtraction (from the accumulator)
- a division (to calculate the average, done in a smart way can be a shift right)

For a total of about 4 algebric sums and a division (or shift)

### EDIT:

For taking into account the time from the last sample as a weighting factor, you can divide the value for the ratio between this time and the averaging time, and you obtain an already weighted average, without having to divide the accumulator.

I added this part because it doesn't add computational load, so you can implement quite easy if you want to.

Comment: With that would you be managing multiple arrays/accumulators so that you could keep updating the rolling average?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I can just .shift() off the end and subtract that from my accumulator.  I think that would work...

Comment: So you rolling average has to have the same number of outputs as inputs? So i have to rethink the solution...but yeah, you can just generate that structure for each input sample...but i don't know if it's still efficient...

Answer (score 0):

The answer from clabacchio has the basics right, but perhaps you need a bit more sophisticated answer.

**Calculating the average:**

```
0.25 - 100
0.50 - 102
1.00 - 110
```

In the above subset of the data what is the answer you want? You could use the mean of these numbers or you could do it in a weighted fashion. You could convert the data into:

```
0.50 - 0.25 = 0.25  ---- (100+102)/2 = 101
1.00 - 0.50 = 0.50  ---- (102+110)/2 = 106
```

Then you can take the weighted average of these values, weight being the time difference, and value being the average value.

The final answer = (0.25*101 + 0.5*106)/(0.25+0.5) = whatever the value is.

**Now coming to "moving" averages:**

You can either use previous k values or previous k seconds worth of data. In both cases you can keep two sums: weighted sum and sum of weights.

Answer (score 0):

So... the worst case scenario is 4 readings per second over 7 seconds = 28 values in your array to process. That will be done in nanoseconds anyway, so not worth optimizing IMHO.